# Redux is dispatching action more than once even if it's dispatched in just one function once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

So, I want to directly replace the value of priority which is initially 1 to a different value. I created a redux function for it, but it's sending the function more than once.

Action

```
export const editPriority = (id, listID, newPriority) => {
  return {
    type: TRELLO_CONSTANTS.PRIORITY,
    payload: { id, listID, newPriority },
  };
};
```

```
case TRELLO_CONSTANTS.PRIORITY: {
      const { id, newPriority } = action.payload;
      const card = state[id];
      card.priority = newPriority;
      return { ...state, [`card-${id}`]: card };
    }
```

```
export const TRELLO_CONSTANTS = {
  PRIORITY: 'PRIORITY',
};
```

and here's my function -

```
import {editPriority} from './actionTypes.js';

const card=({dispatch})=> {
  const [newPriority, priority] = useState(); 
}

const changePriority = (e) => {
    // newPriority(e);
    priority(e);
    dispatch(editPriority(id, listID, priority));
    console.log(priority);
  };

// and the main function


 <button onClick={changePriority(1)}>1</button>
<button onClick={changePriority(2)}>0</button>

{priority === 0 ? <p>0</p> : null}
{priority === 1 ? <p>1</p> : null}
```

Is there something wrong with the priority reducer?

Answer (score 1):

You are **calling** the `changePriority` function in your onClick handler. Just pass the function reference

```js
<button onClick={() => changePriority(1)}>1</button>
<button onClick={() => changePriority(2)}>0</button>
```

Comment: {priority === 0 ? <p>0</p> : null}

This thing is still not working. Plus in dispatch, it is only sending id and listID, not priority